# Java: Group arraylist records by derived attribute

Tags: java, date, csv, arraylist

I have an ArrayList that is created from an input CSV file, in which some calculations will be performed to generate more columns which is to be afterwards printed into another CSV file. In the ArrayList, one of the attributes is a Unix time stamp. The record comprises of about 7 different days. What I want to do is to group the records by day, then if it's not in order, order the groups by time (the specifics, i.e. hours, minutes, seconds). So, from my input CSV file, I extracted the Unix timestamp using a delimiter, e.g. `1442327884`, then I used this code to retrieve the day

```
java.util.Date time = new java.util.Date((long) timeStamp * 1000);
// gives a result of Tue Sep 15 22:38:04 SGT 2015
String date = String.valueOf(time.getDate());;
// gives the result of "15"
```

A method I used for another calculation for grouping by is as follows

```
Map<String, List<String>> groups = data.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.split(",")[1]));
```

How do I set it to groupBy `String date` as mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

You could check out [radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort). That does exactly the kind of sorting you're looking for.